# Google Chrome process stopped when initially launched from Spotlight

Tags: google-chrome, spotlight

Why would Chrome be stopped when launched from Spotlight?

By "stopped," I mean that *ps(1)* shows a single Chrome process as state `T`, and that issuing a `kill -CONT` fixes things.  That is, the CONTinued Chrome process becomes the parent of all subsequent Google Chrome Helper processes and the GUI appears as expected.

For example:

```
$ ps -eo pid,ppid,state,command | grep [C]hrome 
17418     1 T    /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

$ kill -CONT 17418

(...Chrome UI now appears...)

$ ps -eo pid,ppid,state,command | grep [C]hrome
17418     1 S    /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
20087     1 S    /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome Framewo...
20094 17418 S    /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome Framewo...
20095 17418 S    /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome Framewo...
....
```

I think this only happens after a proper login and not, e.g., after resuming from a locked/suspended state.  (Probably because I am launching the very first Chrome process in that case, instead of, I suspect, summoning the GUI from already running processes.)   Thereafter launching Chrome from Spotlight works as expected.

macOS Big Sur 11.6.8, and Chrome is up to date.